# Transform a combined diff into a patch

Tags: git, diff, git-merge

The `git diff` manual [says...](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format)

> Chunk header format is modified to prevent people from accidentally feeding it to patch -p1. 
>   Combined diff format was created for review of merge commit changes, and was not meant for 
>   apply. The change is similar to the change in the extended index header...

Sometimes it would be nice to feed it to `patch` though. Is there a way to convert a combined diff into a normal one which is suitable for `diff`/`git apply`?

Comment: See [Rebase a merge commit when parents changed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23923881/323407) for the motivation behind this.

Comment: I have tried a simple replacement: `git show --no-prefix <commit> | sed '/^---/! s/^--/-/g; /^+++/! s/^++/+/g; s/@@@ \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) @@@/@@ \1 \3 @@/g'` - the result looks like a correctly formatted patch, and `git apply` does not complain about the syntax, but the patch does not apply.

Comment: You're probably better off using `-m` to get diffs of the merge vs each individual parent (a two-parent merge thus produces two separate patches, rather than a 2-element combined patch, with `-m`).

Comment: @torek: that will show both the changes made in the merge commit and those in the other parent, mashed together.